# Nest / Multer / JavaScript - File Upload - Unexpected end of form

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, nestjs, multer

I'm creating a Nest.js server application, and I have already added the upload file functionality, as follows:

```
@Post('upload')
@UseInterceptors(FileInterceptor('file'))
upload(@UploadedFile() file: Express.Multer.File) {
  console.log(file);
}
```

If I try this endpoint on postman or insomnia all works just fine, the problem begins when I try it using JavaScript/React, so, I have the following code in my React.js project:

```js
function App() {
  const [state, setState] = useState(null);

  const handleChange = e => {
    console.log(e.target.files);
    setState(e.target.files[0]);
  };

  const handleSubmit = async e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const url = 'http://localhost:3000/upload';

    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', state);

    console.log(JSON.stringify(formData));
    const response = await fetch(url, {
      method: 'POST',
      body: formData,
      headers: {
        'content-type': 'multipart/form-data; boundary=X-INSOMNIA-BOUNDARY',
        Accept: '*/*'
      }
    });
    console.log(response);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <input type="file" name="files" onChange={handleChange} />
      <button onClick={handleSubmit}>Upload</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

If I send the request here I get a `500` response from the server and the terminal of the server throws me the following error:

> [Nest] 111577  - 12/10/2022, 19:18:39   ERROR [ExceptionsHandler] Unexpected end of form
> Error: Unexpected end of form

Does anyone know why this error is? and why don't I get this error in postman?

Comment: Did you try just removing content-type in fetch request and don't convert string to JSON. If it doesn't work again you can use axios package because as I know nest can infer automatically form data.

Comment: I already tried removing the content type but it won't work (another error for bad format). JSON.stringify is just for the console.log

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the same problem (actually with Express and Multer instead of NestJS and Multer) by downgrading Multer to 1.4.3.

See https://github.com/expressjs/multer/issues/1144