# NestJS File Uploader Multer - Unexpected end of form

Tags: file, upload, nestjs, multer

I have attempted to setup a NESTJS services with the native Express systema and the Multer Fileuploader. It also has Auth, config module and uses the express-ping module. The setup is pretty basic and the following is an example that I simplified it.

main.ts

```
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';
import * as health from 'express-ping';

async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule, {
    logger: ['verbose'],
  });

  app.enableCors();
  app.use(health.ping('/health'));
  await app.listen(3000);
}
bootstrap();
```

app.module.ts

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { RouterModule } from '@nestjs/core';
import { routes } from './services/configuration/routes';
import { FormatModule } from './controllers/format/format.module';
import { ConfigModule } from '@nestjs/config';

@Module({
  imports: [
    ConfigModule.forRoot({
      isGlobal: true,
    }),
    FormatModule,
    RouterModule.register(routes),
  ],
  controllers: [],
  providers: [],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

format.module.ts

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { FormatController } from './format.controller';

@Module({
  imports: [],
  controllers: [FormatController],
})
export class FormatModule {}
```

format.controller.ts

```
import {
  Controller,
  Post,
  UploadedFile,
  UseInterceptors,
} from '@nestjs/common';
import { FileInterceptor } from '@nestjs/platform-express';

@Controller()
export class FormatController {
  
  @Post('psv-to-json')
  @UseInterceptors(FileInterceptor('file'))
  async convertPsvToJson(
    @UploadedFile() file: Express.Multer.File,
  ): Promise<object> {
    return Promise.resolve(file);
  }

  @Post('xls-to-json')
  @UseInterceptors(FileInterceptor('file'))
  async convertXlsToJson(
    @UploadedFile() file: Express.Multer.File,
  ): Promise<object> {
    return Promise.resolve(file);
  }
}
```

routes.ts

```
import { Routes } from '@nestjs/core';
import { FormatModule } from '../../controllers/format/format.module';
import { AppModule } from '../../app.module';

export const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '/api',
    module: AppModule,
    children: [
      {
        path: '/format',
        module: FormatModule,
      },
    ],
  },
];
```

I keep getting the following error when attempting to upload a file after the second time:

error:

```
return cb(new Error('Unexpected end of form'));
                ^
Error: Unexpected end of form
    at Multipart._final (.../node_modules/busboy/lib/types/multipart.js:588:17)
    at callFinal (node:internal/streams/writable:757:12)
    at prefinish (node:internal/streams/writable:769:7)
    at finishMaybe (node:internal/streams/writable:779:5)
    at Multipart.Writable.end (node:internal/streams/writable:687:5)
    at IncomingMessage.onend (node:internal/streams/readable:756:10)
    at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:628:28)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (node:events:514:28)
    at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1408:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21)
```

In researching this problem the error is related to an unresolved promise error or missing async awaits. I reviewed my custom code and there does not appear to be any of the issues above. This crashes the server when this occurs.

The client code look like the following. It takes in memory data and attempts the upload a file. As you can see from the comments I have tired different ways to implement it. And the bigger problem is the server side.

```
async function transformDocumentToObject(baseUrl, apiToken, updatedDocument) {
  //const randomFilePath = `${os.tmpdir()}/${await randomCharacters(36)}.${fileType}`;

  //await fs.writeFileSync(
  //  randomFilePath,
  //  await generateBufferFromString(JSON.stringify(updatedDocument))
  //);
  const bufferData = Buffer.from(updatedDocument, 'utf8');  
  const data = new FormData();

  //let bufferData = await generateBufferFromString(updatedDocument)
  const streamData = await generateStreamFromString(bufferData);
  data.append('file', streamData);
  
  /*const config = {
    method: 'post',
    maxBodyLength: Infinity,
    url: `${baseUrl}/format/psv-to-json`,
    headers: { 
      'Authorization': `Bearer ${apiToken}`, 
      ...data.getHeaders()
    },
    data : data
  };
  
  return await axios.request(config)
    .then((response) => {
      console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data));
      return 
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
    });
    */
  
  const contentLength = bufferData.length
  const headers = {
    Authorization: `Bearer ${apiToken}`,
    'Content-Length': contentLength,
    ...data.getHeaders(),
  };
  try {
    return await axios.post(`${baseUrl}/format/psv-to-json`, data, {
      
      headers: headers,
    });
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
    throw e;
  }
}
```

I am using NodeJS - v20.8.0
Here is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "data-format-service",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "",
  "author": "",
  "private": true,
  "license": "UNLICENSED",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "nest build",
    "format": "prettier --write \"src/**/*.ts\" \"test/**/*.ts\"",
    "start": "nest start",
    "start:dev": "nest start --watch",
    "start:debug": "nest start --debug --watch",
    "start:prod": "node dist/main",
    "lint": "eslint \"{src,apps,libs,test}/**/*.ts\" --fix",
    "test": "jest",
    "test:watch": "jest --watch",
    "test:cov": "jest --coverage",
    "test:debug": "node --inspect-brk -r tsconfig-paths/register -r ts-node/register node_modules/.bin/jest --runInBand",
    "test:e2e": "jest --config ./test/jest-e2e.json"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@nestjs/common": "^10.2.10",
    "@nestjs/config": "^3.1.1",
    "@nestjs/core": "^10.2.10",
    "@nestjs/passport": "^10.0.2",
    "@nestjs/platform-express": "^10.2.10",
    "convert-excel-to-json": "^1.7.0",
    "csv": "^6.3.5",
    "dot-object": "^2.1.4",
    "express-list-routes": "^1.1.9",
    "express-ping": "^1.4.0",
    "jwks-rsa": "^3.1.0",
    "passport": "^0.6.0",
    "passport-jwt": "^4.0.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.13",
    "rxjs": "^7.8.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@nestjs/cli": "^10.2.1",
    "@nestjs/schematics": "^10.0.3",
    "@nestjs/testing": "^10.2.10",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.21",
    "@types/jest": "29.5.10",
    "@types/multer": "^1.4.11",
    "@types/node": "20.9.4",
    "@types/supertest": "^2.0.16",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^6.12.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^6.12.0",
    "eslint": "^8.54.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^9.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^5.0.1",
    "jest": "29.7.0",
    "prettier": "^3.1.0",
    "source-map-support": "^0.5.21",
    "supertest": "^6.3.3",
    "ts-jest": "29.1.1",
    "ts-loader": "^9.5.1",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.1",
    "tsconfig-paths": "4.2.0",
    "typescript": "^5.3.2"
  },
  "jest": {
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "js",
      "json",
      "ts"
    ],
    "rootDir": "src",
    "testRegex": ".*\\.spec\\.ts$",
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.(t|j)s$": "ts-jest"
    },
    "collectCoverageFrom": [
      "**/*.(t|j)s"
    ],
    "coverageDirectory": "../coverage",
    "testEnvironment": "node"
  }
}
```

From what I gather, there should be an error on the the server side regardless. In trouble shooting it never makes to to the controller code. My suspicion is the error is coming from the Multer File Uploader plugin but not sure.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: I just found the following:
https://github.com/expressjs/multer/issues/1144
This appears to be an open issue with multer. Attempting to downgrade based on the following stack overflow article.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74049253/nest-multer-javascript-file-upload-unexpected-end-of-form